# The 'Debug.Assert' statement does not work in Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I have this program here:

```
namespace TodoPlus {
    using System.Diagnostics;

    public class LameProg {

        public LameProg() {}

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            int a = 2;
            int b = 3;
            Debug.Assert(a == b, "Bleh");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Haha, it didn't work");
        }
    }
}
```

And somehow, Debug.Assert is not working.

I am using Mono 2.10.5 and this is what I use to compile and execute:

```
dmcs LameProg.cs

mono ./LameProg.exe
```

How can I make this work? I wish it to have the same effect as the assert macro in C, which is to say it should just downright crash the program.  Is it possible to do this with Debug.Assert or is there some other function that achieves this?

Comment: Don't really like IDEs but thanks for the suggestion. Ideally there should be a way to make such things work without using IDEs.

Comment: That's the big advantage of open source, you can change it the way you like.  Have to rtfm first though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug.Assert seems not to work in Mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245314/debug-assert-seems-not-to-work-in-mono)

Comment: Re *"...the assert macro in C, which is to say it should just downright crash the program."*: It doesn't crash the program. A common consequence is to *abort* the program, but it is entirely implementation-dependent. For instance, in a Visual Studio / C / Windows environment it may throw a dialog box instead of aborting. And it may be possible to provide your own handler to, for example, log the assert (say, to a log file with a timestamp).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. [Debug.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx) is annotated with [[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx). This means that all invocations are removed by the compiler unless the DEBUG preprocessor symbol is defined. Try this:

   ```
   $ dmcs -d:DEBUG LameProg.cs
   ```
2. Mono does not show a dialog box like Microsoft's .NET implementation when an assertion is hit. You need to set a  [TraceListener](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aSystem.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener), e.g.

   ```
   $ export MONO_TRACE_LISTENER=Console.Error
   $ mono LameProg.exe
   ```

---

[Debug.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx) invocations are typically used in debug builds and removed from release builds. If you want to make sure that a certain condition holds, and this check should be present in release builds, use an `if` statement and `throw` an exception:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    if (a != b)
    {
        throw new Exception("Bleh");
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine("Haha it didn't work");
}
```

Comment: Another option, not necessarily a better one is Trace.Assert(...) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk4kachs.aspx

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, but I tried
dmcs -d:DEBUG LameProg.cs
mono ./LameProg.exe

and it didn't work. Same thing for Trace.Assert

Comment: Even better answer to be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245314/debug-assert-seems-not-to-work-in-mono, originally taken from here http://ebsteblog.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/debugassert-and-mono/

Comment: And `export MONO_TRACE_LISTENER=Console.Out` can be used to dump asserts on stdout instead of stderr. For me execution does not stop at the assert. Why the heck isn't printing Debug.Asserts to stderr/stdout the default for mono?

Comment: Omg, it looks like an evil joke — the only thing that Assert in the end does in Mono, is just a print. Just horrible, Assertion supposed to close the program as something fatal, but not just print out a stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

There's another trick: you can add "exit now" behavior through a TraceListener, because Debug.Assert failures trigger a call to Fail() in the trace listener.

You still need to -define:DEBUG (and TRACE?). I personally expect Assert() calls (in DEBUG builds) to stop my program, dump debug info and exit. So, this is how I do it:

In my code I install a custom trace listener to dump stack and add a call to Exit(). And viola! You have an industry standard response to Assert.Fail(). You could also, for example, print timestamps here, etc.

```
public class DumpStackTraceListener : TraceListener
{
  public override void Write( string message )
  {
     Console.Write( message );
  }

  public override void WriteLine(string message)
  {
     Console.WriteLine( message );
  }

  public override void Fail(string message)
  {
     Fail( message, String.Empty );
  }

  public override void Fail(string message1, string message2)
  {
     if (null == message2)
        message2 = String.Empty;

     Console.WriteLine( "{0}: {1}", message1, message2 );
     Console.WriteLine( "Stack Trace:" );

     StackTrace trace = new StackTrace( true );
     foreach (StackFrame frame in trace.GetFrames())
     {
        MethodBase frameClass = frame.GetMethod();
        Console.WriteLine( "  {2}.{3} {0}:{1}", 
                           frame.GetFileName(),
                           frame.GetFileLineNumber(),
                           frameClass.DeclaringType,
                           frameClass.Name );
     }

#if DEBUG
     Console.WriteLine( "Exiting because Fail" );
     Environment.Exit( 1 );
#endif
  }
}
```

Combine with a call to:

```
#if DEBUG
   Debug.Listeners.Add( new DumpStackTraceListener() );
#endif
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. This is the most useful answer I've seen so far.

Comment: No big deal. People are entitled to their opinions, even if their opinion is that I am wrong! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need two things: the DEBUG attribute to the compiler, and a 'trace listener' for the runtime.  I got it to work with

```
% export MONO_TRACE_LISTENER=Console.Error
% mcs -define:DEBUG -debug Prog.cs
% mono Prog.exe
```

That still doesn't exit immediately on assertion failure as I would have expected, but at least it prints something.