# Debug.Assert seems not to work in Mono

Tags: c#, mono

Consider the following C# program:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
        class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false);
            Debug.Fail("fail!");
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

When compiling this using:

```
dmcs -debug -d:DEBUG Main.cs
```

and then running it with:

```
mono --debug Main.exe
```

the assertion and fail seem to be ignored. The output is just:

```
Hello World!
```

I checked other related questions on StackOverflow, but I could not find a solution. In particular the solution give in [Mono - Debug.Assert does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479636/mono-debug-assert-does-not-work) does not work. (UPDATE: the updated solution does work, see below comments.)

I use Mono 2.10.5-1 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: D'oh. I assumed that my answer worked as it was accepted. I've updated the answer and double-checked that it works this time. In short: `mono` doesn't come with a dialog box like Microsoft's .NET; it does nothing unless you set a trace listener.

Comment: Thanks. Using "export MONO_TRACE_LISTENER=Console.Out", the assertion failure is written to the console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C# on mono - http://ebsteblog.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/debugassert-and-mono/

Excerpt from the article:

...if you create a .config file for your app and set the assertuienabled attribute to true, you get the same dialog as with .NET...  File app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <assert assertuienabled="true" />
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Old answer: C++ comment if you did not specify -define DEBUG on command line/compile options.

For debug add

```
#define DEBUG
```

at the beginning of the code or

```
#define TRACE
```

for trace.

See the solution here: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2006-December/033774.html

p.s: I tried this with C++ not C#. This may not work for C#.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. Even met #define DEBUG at the start of the code, the assert and fail are ignored.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I put the xml described on that webpage in  a file Main.exe.config in the same directory as Main.exe. After that, an assertion failure yields a dialogue box.

Comment: @Emir Akaydın, check if my move of comment to answer is ok with you; Jan-Willem, consider accepting Emir's answer since the comment helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xml configuration, or you can place it under the control of your program by adding a trace listener at runtime:

```
var tl = new System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners.Add ( tl );
```

This has the added advantage of you being able to enable it after the program has started.